# GRASS GIS i.sentinel.mask Error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sentinel-2, satellite, cloud-cover

I am trying to run i.sentinel.mask in GRASS GIS 7.8.5

I am having the following Error:

```
ERROR: Option <input_file> is mutually exclusive with all of <blue>, <green>, <red>, <nir>, <nir8a>, <swir11>, <swir12> and <mtd_file>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that (as the error message suggests) you can set **either** the input text file with band names, or specify each band. But you can't mix. So either prepare a text file as explained in the `i.sentinel.mask` [man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/i.sentinel.mask.html), or specify each band individually as input, without the text file input.